# Dataproc notebook cannot import or export to BigQuery : Class Not Found Exception

Tags: apache-spark, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataproc

Here is the spark session I am making. I include the latest jar for spark big query connector for Dataproc 1.5 .

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("GCS to BigQuery - Dev") \
.config('spark.jars', 'gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-latest_2.12.jar').getOrCreate() 

df = spark.read \
  .format('bigquery') \
  .option('table', 'publicdata.samples.shakespeare') \
  .load()
```

Here's the exception :

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o228.load. : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: bigquery
```

Edit 1: I have created the cluster from UI and not shell. I have seen solutions where when people add the jar file while creating the cluster from shell , this seems to work. But I am very curious as to why, when doing it from UI , it wont work.

Edit 2:  I am using jupyter notebook to run the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything works fine If you just regress to the Dataproc image 1.4 and use the connector jar `gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-latest.jar`

Answer (score 0):

I think the description in [SPARK-21752](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-21752) is relevant - by this time the application is already launched and you cannot change its classpath. Please try to run with `pyspark --jars gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-latest_2.12.jar` (and then you can skip the `.config()` part.

Comment: before creating a spark session , I ran `!pyspark --jars gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-latest_2.12.jar` in the notebook . But then I get an error regarding `ZMQError: Address already in use` .

Comment: Is there really no way to import/export to BQ from notebook , and can only be done during runtime by including the jar file with properties argument or from within the script with the pyspark's jar argument

Comment: Which notebook are you using? Please update the question accordingly

Comment: Included an edit in my question . I am using jupyter notebook web interface.